# CheckAndPut operation with multiple columns

Tags: hbase

I'm working on a prototype to evaluate the use of HBase in a real project (or not, depending on the results of the prototype). In the schema I'm working on I have multiple columns in the same column family and I need to update several of them atomically (always within the same row). I made some tests with the checkAndPut method of the client api, but it seems to only support comparing one value (and hence one value to be set in the put parameter). Am I understanding this correctly? If so, is there another approach to do what I need?

Comment: ?what version of HBase are you using

Comment: I'm using the latest stable version, which is 0.94.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set all the PUT operations of a single row together using [RowMutations](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/RowMutations.html) and get all the changes as atomic unit.

Comment: That will solve the problem of altering different columns in the same row atomically, but I can't see how to use the functionality of the checkAndPut method (perform a put operations only if the value stored matches the checkAndPut parameter) together with RowMutations. Can you point me to a page with an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would probably not use HBase for a use case like this. but if you must you can lock the row, read, update if needed - read more about lock and some of its problems here http://www.ngdata.com/hbase-row-locks/ . Again, I'd try to rethink the scenario for instance, HBase support multiple version so you can update anyway and sort things later (e.g. in a coprocessor that runs after update)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, I will read it and see if I can solve the problem with all this information. If not I will consider to change the design as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I redesign my use case. So now this scenario is no longer necessary. I will accept your answer since it triggers that decision :) Thank you very much!

Comment: `RowLock` and associated operations are deprecated in 0.94 and removed in 0.96. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-7315

Comment: @MattBall and rightfully so - as I said, locking isn't a good scenario for HBase anyway